# simple proximity sensor msg

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to connect a simple driver for a proximity sensor that only returns a Boolean answer for a preset range.
It seems that all the messages under sensor_msgs require a more complex answer like: "what is the range".
Well, I don't have that answer, I only have "yes/no".

Am I missing something?

Thanks,

Moshe

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192180/simple-proximity-sensor-msg/) by [MosheS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20148/moshes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2014-09-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Create your own [custom message](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv#Creating_a_msg) with [bool](http://wiki.ros.org/msg#Message_Description_Specification) data  type.

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MosheS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20148/moshes/) on 2014-09-09**:
Well, I guess that this is what I should do then.
I thought that maybe I'm missing something.
Thanks,